# How to show that $\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{(k+1)^{2}}$ converges?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show that the sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{(k+1)^{2}}$ converges. I actually proved that it converges by using the Reimann sum showed that it approaches $\log(2)$. But how can I show it using basic theorems for sequences? I'm trying to help a student that didn't study functions/integrals yet. Only plain limits with sequences. Is it possible to do with sequences?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n&=\frac{2n+2}{(2n+3)^2}+\frac{2n+1}{(2n+2)^2}-\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{2n+2}{(2n+3)^2}+\frac{2n+1}{(2n+2)^2}-\frac{4n}{(2n+2)^2}\\
&=\frac{2n+2}{(2n+3)^2}-\frac{2n-1}{(2n+2)^2}\\
&=\frac{(2n+2)^3-(2n-1)(2n+3)^2}{(2n+3)^2(2n+2)^2}\\
&=\frac{4n^2 + 18n + 17}{(2n+3)^2(2n+2)^2}\\
&>0.
\end{align*}
$$
So, this sequence is monotone increasing.  So, if we can show that it is bounded above, then it must necessarily converge.

To do that, let's do something really naive: note that for $n\leq k\leq 2n$, we have
$$
\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}\leq\frac{2n}{(n+1)^2}\leq\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac{2}{n}.
$$
This implies that
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}\leq\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{2}{n}=\frac{2(n+1)}{n}=2+\frac{1}{n}\leq 3.
$$

Comment: why $n\leq k\leq 2n$?

Comment: A little remark: by adding and subtracting 1 at the numerator you may see that this is equivalent to show that $\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k+1}$ converges. It is the same thing but it makes the computations shorter.

Comment: @vesii Because that's the range of $k$ in the summation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac x{(x+1)^{2}}$ is decreasing on $[1, \infty)$ so  $\frac k{(k+1)^{2}} <\int_{k-1}^{k} \frac x{(x+1)^{2}}dx$ for each $k$. Summing over $k$ we get$\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n}\frac k{(k+1)^{2}} <\int_{n-1}^{2n} \frac x{(x+1)^{2}}$. Evaluate this integral explicitly by writng the numerator as $(x+1)-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to help a student that didn't study functions/integrals yet. Only plain limits with sequences. Is it possible to do with sequences?

Comment: And after the hint, which are the basic theorems for sequences to be used? (Or we use Riemann sums, as the OP claims to know, get the result, $\log 2$, and then use the basic theorem for the sequence $0,0,0,...$, we add it and use the fact that it converges to zero.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint

you may start from here
$$
\sum\limits_{k = n}^{2n} {{k \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} }}}
  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {{{n + j} \over {\left( {n + 1 + j} \right)^{\,2} }}}
  = {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {{{1 + j/n} \over {\left( {1 + {{1 + j} \over n}} \right)^{\,2} }}} 
$$

Comment: And which basic theorem for sequences applies now?

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$
\sum_{n\le k\le 2n}\frac k{k^2}
\le
\sum_{n\le k\le 2n}\frac k{(k+1)^2}
\le
\sum_{n\le k\le 2n}\frac {k+1}{(k+1)^2}
\ .
$$
So it is enough to show the existence of the limit of $(b_n)$ given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
b_n
&=
\sum_{n< k\le 2n}\frac k{k^2}
=
\sum_{n< k\le 2n}\frac 1k
=
\sum_{1\le k\le 2n}\frac 1k
-
\sum_{1\le k\le n}\frac 1k
\\
&=
\sum_{1\le k\le 2n}\frac 1k
-
2\sum_{1\le k\le n}\frac 1{2k}
\\
&=
\frac 11-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+\dots+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac 1{2n}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now use the Leibniz ([Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), or group the terms in pairs
and show that $\displaystyle \frac 1{1\cdot 2}+ \frac 1{3\cdot 4}+\dots
+ \frac 1{(2n-1)\cdot (2n)}$ is increasing and bounded.
Now we may consider the harmonic series, and need for it the logarithmic estimation.

(Alternatively use the logarithmic Euler estimate for the harmonic sequence $(b_n)$ to also have the limit.)

Answer (score 0):

if we have $f(x) > 0$ but $f'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

so we take $a=n, b =2n$ and $$f(x) = \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{1}{1+x}  -\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

$$ \int_n^{2n+1} \; \frac{1}{1+x}  -\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=n}^{2n} \; \frac{j}{(1+j)^2} \; < \; \int_{n-1}^{2n} \; \frac{1}{1+x}  -\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}  \; dx   $$

An antiderivative is $$ \log (1+x) + \frac{1}{1+x}  $$

$$  \log 2 -\frac{1}{2(1+n)}   < \; \sum_{j=n}^{2n} \; \frac{j}{(1+j)^2} \; < \; \log \left( 2 + \frac{1}{n}\right) - \frac{n+1}{2n^2+n} $$

[image]